# Shower head with nice conical flow

Tags: water, shower

I've tried three replacement shower heads from the DIY store (to replace the one that broke, which unfortunately was thrown out by spouse).

I'd like one that makes a wide conical flow, so that my arms receive warm water while showering, without having to move from side to side when I'm standing under the shower.

Also, I'd like it to spray the water with a lot of force.  The shower heads I've tried so far only spray with force from very specific nozzles.  I'd like it to spray with force from all the nozzles.  That way, I'm hopeful the hot water would last for two people to shower one after the other.  The one that broke did fine, both in the pressure and the wide cone.

What descriptors should I look for, to find the right kind?

Comment: Force and duration have little to do with each other.  Duration is about how much water you use before your hot water tank exhausts.  To maximize that, minimize flow.  You do understand your water tank runs out of hot water and then needs 30-60min to recover, yes?

Comment: Before the mishap, we didn't have a problem.  (New water heater installed a few months ago.)  I want the force because... I want the force, without having to dial the shower up to maximum amount of water.

Comment: Was your old shower head old?  The Energy Policy Act of 1992 changed shower heads from high flow to maximum flow of 2.0 GPM.

Comment: @Tyson - Oh, gee.  That might explain why the two recommenders were so happy with their simple shower heads.

Comment: @aparente001 my first house had an original 1950's shower head.  I had no idea that wasn't re-purchasable.  I wish I had taken that shower head when I sold the place, I still miss it. (No I don't miss the house, it was awful, just the shower head.)

Comment: @aparente001 modern shower heads can do the same job with half the water. This also means half the *hot* water so it saves energy too.

Comment: @JimStewart - If the shower head has too concentrated a cone of water spray, then it takes me longer to warm up, and I take a longer shower.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that a Navy Shower Head does a great job of wide spray (for hitting your entire body at once), good pressure (for washing hair), and it's rated low-flow so you should be able to get 2 hot showers back-to-back (provided you don't take 3-hour showers).

There are a few items called "Navy Shower Head"--this is the one I'm referring to: https://www.build.com/delta-52652-pk-shower-head/s244417?uid=1907341 You should be able to find it at most big-box home improvement stores and online.

Comment: And it's so affordable.  I never would have picked something like this out on my own.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is 1 other shower head that you should consider and it is similar to the 1 that @Dave Cripps mentioned, is made by the same company, can be bought at the same store, has a wider spray, and I have used these 20+ years. It is made by Delta and is Model 52650-PK. I paid about $15.00 dollars with free shipping from Home Depot but can be bought from almost any big box store and Amazon. Check it out,

Answer (score 0):

I think that shower heads which are hand-holdable work well in the modern era of water conservation.

Of course, the "Navy" head has a shut-off valve that allows convenient shutting off of the water during the shower. This saves water and allows applying soap without it getting immediately washed off by the spray. But while this valve is off the tubing past the valve will be pressurized. This could conceivably cause leaking around the valve stems or *might not* work well if this is a tub/shower with diverter.